# How to use SherlockFragmentActivity with SlidingMenu?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingdrawer, slidingmenu

Am using [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/) which uses different types of `Fragment/SherlockFragment` as menu.
Am in need of `SherlockFragmentActivity`, as I am using **Tabs** inside menu.

How to use **SherlockFragmentActivity** with SlidingMenu?

If it's not possible, is there any other library through which I can have **sliding menu & tabs inside sliding menu**? Am not sure if it can be achieved using [android-menudrawer](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer/)

**Edit :** want to achieve the below. ie, **Tabs inside Menu**
when menu button is clicked, menu Fragment is opened, inside [Menufragment](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/example/AttachExample.java#L36) I want to add tabs.

[image: This is home screen]   [image: Menu With Tabs]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I wanted to take this design as a challenge and see what is the result:

[image] [image]

As I suggested in the comments, I used [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) and`ViewPager`.

I did not include the `ActionBarSherlock`, but if needed that will be easy to modify: the `MainActivity` will be required to extend from `SherlockFragmentActivity`, and the theme `@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light` added to manifest file, and that is all.

(Just to be sure you got the idea, `PagerSlidingTabStrip` is the one who creates the tabs at the bottom)

Here are the steps I took to integrate PagerSlidingTabStrip and ViewPager with SlidingMenu:

1 - Import [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library into Eclipse workspace
2 - Import [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) library into Eclipse workspace
3 - Add Android Support Library to your project (and copy the same .jar into SlidingMenu and PagerSlidingTabString libraries, otherwise eclipse might complain)
4 - A minimal example of `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setBehindOffset(50);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.left_menu);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }
}
```

5 - The layout of sliding menu, `R.layout.left_menu`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/left_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CCC"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.grec">

    <com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:shouldExpand="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="48dip" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/tabs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

6 - The `ViewPagerAdapter`:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final int PAGES = 3;
    private String[] titles={"Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3"};

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new TabFragment1();
            case 1:
                return new TabFragment2();
            case 2:
                return new TabFragment3();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The item position should be less or equal to:" + PAGES);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGES;
    }
}
```

7 - And an example of fragment, `TabFragment1.java` (the other 2 are similar):

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_1, container, false);
    }
}
```

8 - And the layout of the fragment `R.layout.fragment_tab_1` which is pretty simple, it contains a single `TextView`, so I won't include it here.

I hope this example addresses your issue and will help you getting started on the right track.

Full source on github: https://github.com/vgrec/SlidingMenuWithViewpager

Comment: This line brings menuFragment `.replace(R.id.menu_frame, new SampleListFragment())` But I need `menuActivity`. Still no luck. :(

Comment: mmm... what do you mean by "brings menuFragment". Which menuFragment?

Comment: The menu which appears from side is a fragment, I need to replace menu using Activiy. `new SampleListFragment()` cannot be replaced with an activity, since there is not API for that, **but Tabs can be created only using FragmentActivity not `JUST` Fragments.** So, .... my question again. Try replacing `new SampleListFragment()` with `new SampleListActivity()` if you succeed, let me know how to do it.

Comment: I don't really understand your concern. You can have a `SampleListFragment()` for the sliding menu, and still extend from `FragmentActivity`. Btw, have you looked at the example in the link? that activity extends from `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: I have updated the question, My `mainFragment` extends `FragmentActivity`, but I want my `menu` to extend `FragmentActivity`, or I have to create Tabs using only `Fragment` not [FragmentActivity](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java#L34). To keep it much simpler, can I create Tabs only using Fragments. Any working code?

Comment: you have [demo of creating Tabs](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/example-using-viewpager-with-actionbarsherlock-tabs/) if you see that `MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity`. Can you just use `MainActivity extends SherlockFragment` and create Tabs?

Comment: `Can you just use MainActivity extends SherlockFragment and create Tabs?` - No, only a `Fragment` can extend from `SherlockFragment`. An  `Activity` can extend from `FragmentActivity` or `SherlockFragmentActivity`.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you are trying to do, basically you want to have a `ViewPager` with tabs in the sliding menu, right? If so, then you could use `PagerSlidingTabStrip` to create the tabs (http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/pager-sliding-tabstrip/) and a `ViewPager` to display the content, and you won't need anymore `ActionBarSherlock`. However, a better solution would be to re-think the design, in my opinion. I believe a menu should be treated as such - displaying a list of options menu.

Comment: No, I have no clue how to convey my requirement, from the above images what do you understand?

Comment: One solution would be to put the content of the tabs in separate activities, and then instead of having 3 tabs at the bottom, have 3 options menu that will redirect to specific activities.

Comment: This not my own app, it's a product, I have no rights to change the design. My requirement is fixed and am dead.

Comment: Does it work for API-10? Thanks for the info, will get it done and award if it works. Happy Coding :) May be you should blog this with source code.

Comment: Yes it does work for Api 10. The screenshots are from a Samsung Galaxy Ace device.

Comment: Good idea about blogging, later today I'll put on the blog and upload the source to github.

Comment: You can find the example on github: https://github.com/vgrec/SlidingMenuWithViewpager

Comment: thanks for your help, you should update answer with GitHub link and plz remove my comment in the answer. I have one more doubt, I'll mail you.

Answer (score 1):

1) Add SherlockActionBar library to SlidingMenu 
2) Change `SlidingFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity` to `SlidingFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity`
3) Then add SlidingMenu library to your project and your project should use `MyProjectActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity`

You can use SherlockActionBar to create sliding menu with tabs inside
Here sample code to create Tab with view pager
For sliding, you can look at their documentation

```
public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

```
    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);

    setContentView(mViewPager);
    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);

    mTabsAdapter.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("tab1"), FirstFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("tab2"), SecondFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("tab3"), ThirdFragment.class, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, this is the code for tabs. which extends `FragmentPagerAdapter` I need to achieve the same using Fragment or `SherlockFragment` absolutely nothing else. Since SlidingMenu supports only Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

As what you have said the SlidingMenu uses `fragments` and you want to to have Tabs inside a Menu. For me, using Tabs inside a Menu needs *nested fragments* which means that you can't use `SherlockFragmentActivity` since it is like the `Main` Activity. You can't contain an `Activity` inside a fragment.

I have not implemented this kind of approach but maybe you can try implementing TabListener inside a fragment.

I am using this code for my activity not the fragment,

```
class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
}
```

maybe you can have,

```
 class FragmentA extends SherlockFragment implements TabListener{
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: You are correct., class MainActivity extends `SherlockFragmentActivity`, I want to extend the same in menu, but it's not possible, I am looking for a work around to bring tabs inside menu.

I have updated the question.